# Не берутся значение из тега span

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, не берутся данные, записаны в тег `span`

```js
(function () {
  var el = document.getElementById('rezult');
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClass('sum').innerHTML;
  var sum=0;
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)  {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }
  el.value = sum;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>


<span class="sum">20</span>
<span class="sum">20</span>


<p><input type="submit" value="Считать" onclick="someFunc()" /></p>
результат:<input id="rezult" >
```

Comment: `inputs[i].value` => `inputs[i].innerText`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych не хочет все равно.

Comment: `var inputs = document.getElementsByClass('sum').innerHTML;` => `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych есть, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заменил: `document.getElementsByClass` => `document.getElementsByClassName`
2. Вызвал в цикле: `parseInt(inputs[i].innerHTML)` вместо `parseInt(inputs[i].value)`

```js
(function () {
  var el = document.getElementById('rezult');
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');
  var sum=0;
  
  for (var i=0; i< inputs.length; i++)  {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].innerHTML);
  }
  
  el.value = sum;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>


<span class="sum">20</span>
<span class="sum">20</span>


<p><input type="submit" value="Считать" onclick="someFunc()" /></p>
результат:<input id="rezult" >
```